# Jquery POST for suggestion list

Tags: jquery, post

I have the next code and it works well, the problem is that when the user finishes writing the word, the script keeps creating post calls and changing the suggestion list constantly.

I want to do something that if the user keeps writing a word, the script stops all the post calls to only do the last.

```
$("#inputString").keydown(function() {
lookup($(this).val());
//alert('a');
});

function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) {
    $('#suggestions').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
} else {
    $.post("../jsonshow.php", {q: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
        $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
        $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You only show where the ajax request is made; the change you're asking for probably has to be made in the key binding event, i.e. show more code please

Comment: Also need the binding function that calls lookup()

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to set a certain about of time between keystrokes to allow before the post occurs. - then clear the timer on each keystroke using [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout)

```
var action;
$('#inputString').keydown(function(){
    clearTimeout(action);     
    var $el = $(this);   
    action = setTimeout(function(){
        lookup($el.val());
    },1000); // <-- amount of time in ms before your post will run
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gunuW/

Comment: you set your timeout at 100.. so thats 1/10th of a second. try using a bigger number?

Comment: did you push out the changes to that page you linked?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to send and AJAX request on a keydown event, i.e.:

```
$("#searchBox").keydown(function() {
    lookup($(this).val());
});
```

This will only send an AJAX request when the user types something.

**EDIT:**
I made a JSFiddle, and doing that I realized it had to be `keyup` instead of `keydown` (with keydown you won't get the character that is typed then with the input).

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/11684/sjCTZ/1/

Comment: Have you removed your version of the AJAX call and that eventlistener? @MikelGarcesEtxebarria

Comment: the code now is only that you can see at top of the page message

Comment: Ah, this is what you initially used? Or did you add the version of your code that includes the changes proposed in my answser?

Comment: Working on a JSFiddle for you, it should work. @MikelGarcesEtxebarria

Comment: It now IS a working JSFiddle, I edited my answer. @MikelGarcesEtxebarria

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function lookup(inputString) {
   if (...
   else if (!$("#suggestions").data('blocking')) {
       $("#suggestions").data('blocking', true);
       $.post(...function (data) {
          ...
          $("#suggestions").data('blocking', false);
       });
   }
}
```

This will only perform the ajax request if the mutex set in `$("#suggestions").data('blocking')` is false; it is set to true before the request and set to false after the request completes.

Comment: When the user types in two characters, and the results arrive thereafter, the results for only the first character are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup after typing. Please check the following example: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/check_after_typing.php

Comment: I don't want to do it after typing, but I don't want to wait to all calls per character, I want to do that if I add any character, stops all the calls and do only the last